# Is a bounded operator with finite trace trace class?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ a bounded linear Operator and assume we have an orthonormal basis $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. If $A$ is trace-class, then $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle$ is finite. But what about the *converse*, i.e. if we know that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle<\infty,$$ can we deduce that $A$ is trace class? If not, what can be said if $A$ is known to be positive, i.e. $A\ge 0$?

Comment: The problem is that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle<\infty$ might not be absolutely convergent. For example, if $A$ is a multiplication operator (i.e. $A(x_n)=\lambda_n x_n$), where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent.

Comment: So if the ONB $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is fixed, is it true that $A$ is trace class, if and only if the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: The series might be absolutely convergent so also summable but still the operator may fail to be trace class.

Comment: @RobertRauch: No, that is not true: Absolute convergence does not imply trace class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recall that: $A\in B(\mathcal H)$ is trace-class **iff** if for some (and hence all) orthonormal bases $e_k$ of $\mathcal H$ the sum 
$$Tr(A)=\sum_k\langle (A^*A)^{1/2}e_k,e_k\rangle<\infty.$$

The answer to the first question is **no**. Take e.g. $Ae_k=\lambda_ke_k,\ k\in\mathbb N$ with $\lambda_k=\dfrac{(-1)^k}k.$ Then the alternating series 
$$\sum_k\langle Ae_k,e_k\rangle=\sum_k\dfrac{(-1)^k}k<\infty$$ 
but 
$$\sum_k\langle (A^*A)^{1/2}e_k,e_k\rangle=\sum_k\dfrac1k=+\infty.$$

If $A$ is a positive operator, then $A=(A^*A)^{1/2}$ and we have
$$Tr(A)=\sum_k\langle (A^*A)^{1/2}e_k,e_k\rangle=\sum_k\langle Ae_k,e_k\rangle<\infty,$$ 
so that $A$ is trace class.

Comment: That example lacks summability. So it will fail to converge for some choices of ONB's.

Comment: @Freeze_S I do not see what is wrong with my solution

Comment: Nothing wrong. But your counterexample is not very comprising as though the series converges the sum doesn't. That will force the series to diverge for some ONB. Note the difference between sums $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n:=\{\sum_{n\in N}a_n\}_{N\subseteq\mathbb{N}:\#N<\infty}$ and series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n:=\{\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$. *(See also [Trace](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213342/79762) and [Summability](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1370587/79762).)*

Comment: @Freeze_S Note, that any example will be of that kind. The following is true: if the sum $\sum\langle Ae_n,e_n\rangle<\infty$ for every ONB $\{e_n\}$ iff $A$ is trace class. In particular, if $A$ is a shift operator, then there exists an ONB, where the sum $\sum\langle Ae_n,e_n\rangle$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, but still...

Comment: See there's an important difference: There are ordered sums, a.k.a. series, and unordered sums, a.k.a. sums. However ONB's come as unordered so there's no preferable way of ordering. The most natural then will be by inclusion on finite subsets. That is the net of finite sums or in short sum. This will be evident when considering uncountable ONB's on nonseparable Hilbert spaces that are most of all. But it will be also notable on countable ONB's as there's no preferable way of running through the naturals: Forwards, backwards or cross-cross?!

Comment: Now to the examples: The one you gave exists as series but not as sum. But according to the previous comment that is not what is desired on summation over ONB's. Instead the example I gave is summable.

Comment: Simply said: Series are the wrong concept here.

Comment: Seriously: Downvoted? For what?

Answer (score 5):

*The assertion is false as:*

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider the right shift:
$$A:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):\quad A:=R$$

Then it has finite trace:
$$\sum_n\langle A\delta_n,\delta_n\rangle=\sum_n0=0$$

But it is not trace class:
$$\sum_n\langle|A|\delta_n,\delta_n\rangle=\sum_n1=\infty$$

Concluding counterexample.

Comment: very good example.

Comment: @RaziehNoori: thank you :)

Comment: @RaziehNoori: By the way if you're interested I have a couple of open questions on my MSE page: [Profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79762/freeze-s?tab=profile)

Comment: I am reading your page and question. my phd thesis is about $\frak{E}_{p}(I)$ it is very related to trace class.

Comment: By $\mathfrak{G}_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{I})$ you mean the Schatten classes over a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{I}$?

Comment: Actually there is a problem I'm not yet really satisfied: Every trace class operator is compact. The proof I remember uses its singular value decomposition which seems kind of a circular argument.

Comment: for $\frak{E}_p(I)$ see 28.24 abstract harmoinic analysis hewiit&ross 2 page 70

Comment: I will think about your question.

Comment: @RaziehNoori: Aaaahh so you study direct products of operator algebras. Nice. :) This book is huge. OO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28761/discussion-between-razieh-noori-and-freeze-s).