# Summability: Equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Summability**

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider sums:
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\varphi_\lambda:=\bigg\{\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0}\varphi_\lambda\bigg\}_{\Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda:\#\Lambda_0<\infty}$$

Ordered by inclusion:
$$\Lambda_0,\Lambda_0'\subseteq\Lambda:\quad \Lambda_0\leq\Lambda_0':\iff\Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda_0'$$

*(Distinct to series!)*

**Problem**

Given the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

> Then for sums:
>   $$\sum_\lambda a_\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\iff\sum_\lambda|a_\lambda|\in\mathbb{R}_+$$

How can I prove this?

*(Elegant proof?)*

**Attempt**

By Lipschitz and completeness:
$$\sum_\lambda|a_\lambda|\in\mathbb{R}_+\implies\sum_\lambda a_\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$$

By continuity and linearity:
$$\sum_\lambda a_\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\implies\sum_\lambda\Re a_\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\sum_\lambda a_\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\implies\sum_\lambda\Im a_\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$$

But how to proceed?

Comment: Huh? Let $a_n=(-1)^n/n$. Answer me two questions: (i) Is it true that $\sum a_n\in\mathbb C$? (ii) Is it true that $\sum|a_n|\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Freeze_S Are you talking about nets? How do you define summability?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Sums usually refer to the net of finite sums. Series rather refer to ordered sums. In that case the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}(-1)^n$ converges while the sum $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}(-1)^n$ diverges.

Comment: @Freeze_S: writing something like ${\cal E} \not\in \mathbb{C}$ is a really irritating, far from perspicacious and technically problematic way to say "$\cal E$ is undefined" or "$\cal E$ does not converge".

Comment: Oh. Didn't realize that's what you meant - assumed that $\lambda$ was just an integer index in $\sum_\lambda$. If that's what you mean then yes this is true, and not hard to prove. Give me a minute...

Comment: @RobArthan: Oh, what issue is there with the positive reals?

Comment: Now we have enough details to make an educated guess about what this question means, doesn't it reduce to standard facts about sums of series, given that the sums in question cannot exist if $a_{\lambda}$ is not countably supported?

Comment: For heaven's sake. Next time if you know a proof but want a better one _say_ so, so people don't waste time on the proof you know!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: No everything fine you got me on a nice track I didn't know yet: $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\varphi_\lambda\in E\implies \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0}\varphi_\lambda\in E\quad(\Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify notation that wasn't clear to me at first: Say $f:X\to\mathbb C$. We say $$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=s$$if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite set $F\subset X$ such that if $E$ is finite and $F\subset E\subset X$ then $$\left|s-\sum_{x\in E}f(x)\right|<\epsilon.$$

Lemma: Suppose $f:X\to\mathbb C$ and $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ exists. Suppose $A\subset X$. Then $\sum_{x\in A}f(x)$ exists. (Exercise.)

Lemma: Obvious lemma about the case $0\le g\le f$. (Exercise.)

Lemma: Say $f=g+ih$ where $g$ and $h$ are real-valued. Then $\sum f(x)$ exists if and only if $\sum g(x)$ and $\sum h(x)$ both exist. (Exercise.)

Suppose now that $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ exists. Say $f=g+ih$ as in the lemma. So $\sum g$ and $\sum h$ exist. Write $g=g^+-g^-$, $|g|=g^++g^-$. Let $A$ be the set of $x$ with $g(x)\ge 0$. Then $\sum_Xg^+=\sum_Ag$ exists. Similarly $\sum g^-$ exists. Since $|g|=g^++g^-$ this shows that $\sum_X|g|$ exists. Similarly $\sum|h|$ exists. And so $\sum|f|$ exists, because $0\le|f|\le|g|+|h|$.

Comment: No worry that is **precisely** what I was looking for. Thanks alot!! *(I knew only the count-till-then-change-direction proof.)*